# How do I install sudo insults on Mac?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, sudo, darwin

How do I install sudo insults<sup>*†*</sup> on Mac terminal?

Apparently Apple has cleaned it up from Darwin, so adding `Defaults insults` through `sudo visudo` does not help.

---

*<sup><sup>†</sup> The insulting things sudo command says when you enter wrong password.</sup>*

Answer (score 15):

To install a sudo *with insults* you have to compile it yourself:

Requirements: Xcode 8.0, Sierra 10.12, probably SIP disabled

- Backup sudo and visudo:

  ```
  sudo cp /usr/bin/sudo  /usr/bin/sudo.backup
  sudo cp /usr/sbin/visudo  /usr/sbin/visudo.backup
  ```
- Create a dir: `mkdir sudo`
- Change to the directory: `cd sudo`
- Curl the Apple open source sudo:

  ```
  curl https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/sudo/sudo-83.tar.gz | tar zxf -
  ```
- cd to the source folder:

  ```
  cd sudo-83/src
  ```
- configure, make and make install it:

  ```
  ./configure --with-password-timeout=0 --disable-setreuid --with-env-editor --with-pam --with-libraries=bsm --with-noexec=no --sysconfdir="/private/etc" --with-timedir="/var/db/sudo" --with-all-insults
  make
  sudo make install
  ```

  The file sudo-83/src/INSTALL contains a lot more tweak options for the configure command!
- The files may be installed to /usr/local/bin/ and /usr/local/sbin/ so you may have to move them (in my case I had to):

  ```
  sudo mv /usr/local/sbin/visudo /usr/sbin/visudo
  sudo rm /usr/local/bin/sudoedit
  sudo mv /usr/local/bin/sudoreplay /usr/bin/
  sudo mv /usr/local/bin/sudo /usr/bin/sudo
  /usr/bin/sudo ln -s /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/sudoedit
  ```

  **or** modify your path and prepend /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/sbin.
- Enter `/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/visudo`
- Add the line in *insert mode* (simply hit <kbd>i</kbd>)

  ```
  Defaults        lecture_file = "/etc/sudo_lecture" #<-already there
  Defaults        insults
  ```

  Save the file after hitting <kbd>esc</kbd> with `:wq!`.
- Probably you have to quit and relaunch Terminal now.

Results:

```
host:~ user$ ls -l /usr/bin/sudo*
-rwsr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  restricted 225428 Oct 19 02:01 /usr/bin/sudo
-r-x--x--x  1 root  wheel  restricted 369136 Oct 19 02:00 /usr/bin/sudo.backup
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  restricted     13 Oct 19 02:03 /usr/bin/sudoedit -> /usr/bin/sudo
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  restricted  49544 Oct 19 02:01 /usr/bin/sudoreplay
host:~ user$ sudo openssl sha1 /usr/bin/sudo*
SHA1(/usr/bin/sudo)= 87d9ad990813b5a949d07267d566bb3a1fddeec0
SHA1(/usr/bin/sudo.backup)= 088c317bf7b8a146803533173699021b9aef5b16
SHA1(/usr/bin/sudoedit)= 87d9ad990813b5a949d07267d566bb3a1fddeec0
SHA1(/usr/bin/sudoreplay)= f76c5ad8d6f2aebbc24d77fee54a54ba9d207e25

Last login: Wed Oct 19 02:09:33 on console
host:~ user$ sudo ifconfig
Password:
Do you think like you type?
Password:
He has fallen in the water!
Password:
I don't wish to know that.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

The files may be overwritten after a system update/upgrade!

---

Recompiling sudo *with insults* also works in older systems - you have to choose the respective tarball though (e.g. sudo-73.tar.gz should work with 10.9 and 10.10).

---

By modifying the ins_*.h in the *src* folder you should be able to include more insults. You can also add additional ins_*.h files but then you have to include them in insults.h like the other four already are. You may also include non-english insults of course!

Comment: @displayName I tested the how-to in a virtual machine and it worked. The two sudo files differ notably by size: the original has about 370 KB, the modded (with insults) is much smaller: ~235 KB. Please check this. I may re-run the compilation and check the precise size and/or upload it somewhere

Comment: Just tested it on macOS Mojave 10.14.3 and it worked just fine. Only that the sudo files cannot be replaced and the path has to be updated, as described in the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to recompile `sudo` while still allowing the TouchID trick?

Comment: @MaxCoplan `sudo` shouldn't depend on the auth method. But I can't test this because I don't own any TouchID-device.

Comment: please see [my full question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370373/how-to-add-sudo-insults-with-touchid-without-disabling-sip)