# Where are sudo insults stored on macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, sudo

How do I get all `sudo` insults messages list on macOS?

Comment: You can check if they are hardcoded in binary - use: `sudo strings $(which sudo)`

Comment: Related: [How do I install sudo insults on Mac?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257405/how-do-i-install-sudo-insults-on-mac)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you run `sudo strings /usr/bin/sudo` you get (among a lot of other things)

```
Sudo version %s
1.8.17p1
Configure options: %s
--with-password-timeout=0 --disable-setreuid --with-env-editor --with-pam
--with-libraries=bsm --with-noexec=no --sysconfdir=/private/etc
--without-lecture --enable-static-sudoers --with-rundir=/var/db/sudo
```

For insults to be included, `--with-insults` (or any of the other insult options mentioned in the [INSTALL file](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/file/1.8/INSTALL)) would need to be used when compiling `sudo`:

```
--with-insults
    Define this if you want to be insulted for typing an incorrect password
    just like the original sudo(8).  This is off by default.
    Sudoers option: insults
```

See [How do I install sudo insults on Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257405/how-do-i-install-sudo-insults-on-mac) for instructions on how to compile it yourself.

Comment: so where is the binary file `sudoers.so`  in os x?for example in linux its in `/usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so`

Comment: `sudo` is installed in `/usr/bin/sudo`. Libraries are different in macOS, there probably isn't a static library as such (at least `sudo find /usr -name '*sudo*'`  didn't return anything in that direction)