# How to add Sudo Insults with TouchID without disabling SIP

Tags: password, sudo, touch-id, code-signing

I am following a guide to [recompile sudo](https://egeek.me/2018/03/24/osx-sudo-with-insults/) with insults.  However, I felt uncomfortable disabling SIP so I [modified it](http://disq.us/p/24ed8n7) a bit to allow me to use it with SIP enabled.  Unfortunately recompiling `sudo` broke my ability to authenticate sudo using TouchID.  I [investigated](http://disq.us/p/24etqs2) this and discovered it had to do with the entitlements codesigning used by sudo.

If you look at the Entitlements for `sudo`: 
`sudo cp /usr/bin/sudo . && sudo codesign -d --entitlements :- ./sudo`* you get:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.private.AuthorizationServices</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.security.sudo</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Apparently this `com.apple.private.AuthorizationServices` key is necessary to the enabling of TouchID for sudo.

Proof:
`./sudo ls` prompts me for TouchID ✅

`sudo codesign --remove-signature ./sudo  && sudo -k && ./sudo ls` does not prompt me for TouchID and just asks me for my password ❌

Is this only because I continue to have SIP enabled? Does disabling SIP remove the code signing requirements for TouchID?

Edit 1:
Attempts at fixes: 
What I am trying to do is just remove the code signature from a copy of `/usr/bin/sudo` and allow TouchID with that (so I can be sure any error isn't coming from recompiling)

1. Make an editable copy of `/usr/bin/sudo` to work with: `sudo cp /usr/bin/sudo .`
2. remove code signing `sudo codesign --remove-signature ./sudo`
3. Try to re-apply entitlements `sudo codesign -d --entitlements :- $(which sudo)>entitlements.plist. && sudo codesign --entitlements entitlements.plist -s "signature" ./sudo`
4. Try to execute `./sudo` and see if it prompts for TouchID: `./sudo ls` prints `[1]    12559 killed     ./sudo ls`

So the process is immediately being killed.   I'm guessing macOS is noticing an improperly signed executable and killing it.  What is the proper way to enable TouchID on `./sudo`?

Edit 2:
Does anybody know where I can find logs to help track this?
`Console.app` just says

```
com.apple.libsqlite3    error   14:44:27.950193 -0400   taskgated   cannot open file at line 42270 of [95fbac39ba]
com.apple.libsqlite3    error   14:44:27.950216 -0400   taskgated   os_unix.c:42270: (2) open(/var/db/DetachedSignatures) - No such file or directory
```

Trying to run `sudo dtruss ./sudo` is weird.  It will give me 1 of 4 error messages each time it's run:

1. `dtrace: failed to control pid 13256: process exec'd set-id or unobservable program`
2. `Failed to read dyld info for process 13279 (4)
   dtrace: failed to control pid 13279: process exec'd set-id or unobservable program`
3. `dtrace: failed to execute ./sudo: Could not create symbolicator for task`
4. `Failed to read dyld info for process 13833 (4)
   dtrace: failed to execute ./sudo: Could not create symbolicator for task`

Edit 3:

trying to verify the code sign signature seems to be okay

```bsh
sudo codesign --verify --verbose  ./sudo
./sudo: valid on disk
./sudo: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

spctl says it is rejected, but doesn't give a reason why

```bsh
sudo spctl -a -vvvv ./sudo
./sudo: rejected
origin=Mac Developer: vegerot@mac.com (is the UUID private?)
```

compared to /usr/bin/sudo

```bsh
sudo spctl -a -vvvv $(which sudo)
/usr/bin/sudo: rejected (the code is valid but does not seem to be an app)
origin=Software Signing
```

So even Apple's `sudo` is rejected, but it says the code the valid (I'm guessing `spctl` is only for app bundles (like .app)).  Since it doesn't say `./sudo` is valid, I'm guessing that means it's invalid, but I can't make it give more information

Comment: If you are uncomfortable with removing sip even temporally then note that  messing around with sudo is more risky and as you have shown more complex. Easier to disable sip and reinstate it later

Comment: You're not wrong.  Now it is just more of a curiosity project than anything.  If I have TouchID authentication, I don't really need insults anyways .  What I am interested in now is trying to copy /usr/bin/sudo (that works with TouchID), removing Apple's code signature, and trying to get PAM TouchID to work again

Comment: AppleMobileFileIntegrity is killing it, you should find relevant logs about that in Console